# Determine the center and radius of the circle and sketch the graph of the equation

Tags: calculus

The given equation is
$$16x² + 16y² - 8y - 15 = 0$$

I tried to group the terms with the same variables
$16x² + (16y² - 8y)-15 = 0$

then i moved the constant term outside of the equation

$16x² + (16y² - 8y) = 15$

then i create a perfect square of trinomials, Whatever terms you add to the left side add them also the right side to keep the equation true
$16x²+(16y² - 8y + ¼) = 15+16+¼$

since the there is no value of the **x** i leave 16x² outside 
So the result is $16x² + (16y² - 8y + ¼) = 125/4$
Then i square root into 2 so my final result is

(x - 4)² + ( y - 4 )² = 125/4

So the center and radius of the circle is

h = 4  k = 4   r = (5/2)*Sqrt(5) 
**Note: I use standard form in Transforming The Equations of a Circle**

is this correct? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: No it is not. Please expand $(x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2 = \frac{125}{4}$ and try and bring back to the equation that was given to you originally. Can you do it?

Comment: For example, there is no $x^1$ term in the original equation but it's there in your final equation as part of $(x-4)^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: You're completing the square on $ \ 16· (y^2 \ - \ 1/2 · y) \ $ , so you are going to add a term $ \ ( 1/4 )^2 \ $ , which will be multiplied by $ \ 16 \ $ when you produce the "balancing term".  Also, there is nothing to "complete" for the $ \ x^2-$term, so it remains $ \ 16x^2 \ $ in the circle equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is not correct as noted in the comments. To check your answer, you can expand it and see if it matches the original equation. Expanding $(x-4)^2$ gives the term $-16x$, but there is no term involving $x$ in the original equation as mentioned by Math Lover.

---

We have by completing the square

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a})=a((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2})$$

Expand the RHS to see if you get back to the LHS. (Why is this true?)

---

Then we have

$$16x² + 16y² - 8y - 15 = 0$$
$$16x^2+16(y^2-\frac{1}{2}y-\frac{15}{16})=0$$
$$16x^2+16((y-\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{15}{16}-\frac{1}{16})=0$$
$$16x^2+16(y-\frac{1}{4})^2-16=0$$
$$x^2+(y-\frac{1}{4})^2=1$$

Comment: can you explain how do you get 1/2?

Comment: When you factor $16$ we obtain $\frac{1}{2}$, because $16\cdot\frac{1}{2}=8$ after expanding the bracket. Try expanding the bracket!